# Replace multiple special character to single dash

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hi I Have my data as (SCARF.) / (WRAPS) and I want to show it as SCARF-WRAPS but I am not able to get it

My below code is as

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @specialchars VARCHAR(50) = '%[/,~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!^?:]%'
--SET @str = 'KRA!NTHI@#KUMAR, KU%^?MAR GO~()$U.BigGrin'
SET @str = '(SCARF.) / (WRAPS)'
SET @str = REPLACE(@str,'.','')
WHILE PATINDEX( @specialchars, @str ) > 0
SET @str = REPLACE(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @specialchars, @str ), 1 ),'-'),'-','-')

IF(LEFT(@str, 1) = '-')
   set @str = RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - 1)
IF(RIGHT(@str, 1) = '-')
   set @str = LEFT(@str, LEN(@str) - 1)

SELECT REPLACE(@str,' ','-')
```

but it is giving data as SCARF-----WRAPS instead of SCARF-WRAPS

I have such type of data as multiple and I want to convert them as with single dash.

For example:

> 'SKIN CARE & BEAUTY SUPPLY' should change to 'SKIN-CARE-BEAUTY-SUPPLY'
>
> 'BANDANAS / DURAGS / WRAPS' should change to 'BANDANAS-DURAGS-WRAPS'
>
> 'HATS & MUFFLERS' should change to 'HATS-MUFFLERS'

Comment: @Larnu its 2014, but the code I had return is working in all versions

Comment: SQL is *not* suitable for text processing. It's far easier to clean up text while *loading* the data.  The input you posted requires parsing, not string replacement anyway. You could easily write a regular expression that matches only alphanumeric values inside the parentheses. Doing the same thing with T-SQL is orders of magnitude harder

Comment: Even if you only want to replace multipel non-alpha characters with a single dash, you coud write, eg `someField=Regex.Replace(someField,"[^a-zA-Z\\d]+","-")`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are you asking to use its in sql server? I have tried DECLARE str VARCHAR(400), SET str = '(SCARF.) / (WRAPS)'  select Replace(str,'[^a-zA-Z\\d]+','-') but its not working

Comment: No, I'm saying you should clean up the data *before* inserting it into SQL Server. Or clean it up on the client, before displaying it. T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions

Comment: I want to import existing tables data into another database, NopCommerce converts such data (SCARF.) / (WRAPS) to url SCARF-WRAPS as url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)='(SCARF.) / (WRAPS)'
DECLARE @specialchars VARCHAR(50) = '%[/,~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!^?:-]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @specialchars, @str ) > 0
SET @str = REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @specialchars, @str ), 1 ),' ')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@str)), ' ', '- '), ' -', ''), ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to say this solution is pretty; it's not. it does the job but I don't expect it to work fast. It makes use of Alan Burstein's [`NGrams8k`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/), so you'll need to ensure you have a copy on your server as well.

if you don't understand it, feel free to ask (apart from how NGrams8K works, that's what the article is for):

```
CREATE TABLE T (string varchar(400));
INSERT INTO T
VALUES ('KRA!NTHI@#KUMAR, KU%^?MAR GO~()$U.BigGrin'),
       ('(SCARF.) / (WRAPS)');
GO
WITH Replacements AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN NG.token NOT LIKE '[ /,~@#$%&*().!^?:]' THEN NG.token ELSE '-' END AS TokenR
    FROM T
         CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k ('-'+T.String+'-',1) NG),
Repeating AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN TokenR = '-' AND TokenR = LAG(TokenR) OVER (PARTITION BY string ORDER BY position) THEN NULL ELSE TokenR END AS TokenRR
    FROM Replacements),
Cleaned AS (
    SELECT string,
           STUFF((SELECT sq.TokenRR + ''
                  FROM Repeating sq
                  WHERE sq.TokenRR IS NOT NULL
                    AND sq.string = R.string
                  ORDER BY position
                  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CleanString
    FROM Repeating R
    GROUP BY string)
SELECT string, LEFT(CleanString, LEN(CleanString)-1) AS CleanedString
FROM Cleaned;

GO
DROP TABLE T;
```

With the sample data provided, you get the output below:

```
string                                     | CleanedString
-------------------------------------------|---------------------------------
(SCARF.) / (WRAPS)                         | SCARF-WRAPS
KRA!NTHI@#KUMAR, KU%^?MAR GO~()$U.BigGrin  | KRA-NTHI-KUMAR-KU-MAR-GO-U-BigGrin
```